# column name in alias is getting shortened

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am using below query to create a table

```
CREATE TABLE FINAL_TBL AS  SELECT /*+ leading(e) use_hash(t) full(t) parallel(t,2) */
 t.customer_id
 , max(decode(type,'C',t.num,null)) AS CONTACT_TELNO
 , max(decode(type,'H',t.num,null)) AS  HOME_TELNO
 , max(decode(type,'W',t.num,null)) AS  WORK_TELNO
 , max(decode(type,'O',t.num,null))  AS OTHER_TELNO
 from TABLE_A  e, TMP_NUMBERS   t
 where t.num = e.num
 and e.status = 'P'
 group by t.customer_id
 order by 1;
```

But the table is getting created with the truncated column name as below
CUSTOMER_ID **CONTACT_TE** HOME_TELNO WORK_TELNO **OTHER_TELN**

Why is So? How can I fix it?

Comment: hi, could you add CREATE TABLE statements so we can reproduce the problem. thanks

Comment: Is this being run from sql plus or through some other tool? Column names have a 30 character length limit, but this is truncating at 10. Perhaps it is the client doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you must be running this in SQL*Plus... you need to use the command `COLUMN` with the `FORMAT` option, like so: `column CONTACT_TELEPHONE format a18` (notice no semicolon since this is not a SQL command, it only applies to your interface). The SQL query runs as you expected, but then SQL*Plus formats the result according to its own settings.